# Make install creates wrong file path

Tags: c++, makefile, installation, make-install, torcs

I try to install [Torcs](http://torcs.sourceforge.net/), while `make` works, `make install` stops with an error:

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin//torcs': Permission denied
```

The path is quite obviously wrong I guess, there shouldn't be `//`, but only a single one. How can I fix this? I can't figure out where the wrong path is generated.

Comment: It's unlikely the extra slash is the culprit, are you sure you simply don't have the right permissions? Have you tried `sudo make install`?

Comment: The double slash doesn't influence *anything*. If you want to directly install in your system, run `make install` as root, e.g. using `sudo`. If you want to create a binary package, use something like `make DESTDIR=/home/xyc/torcs-pkg install`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, I noticed the sudo was the problem, but either way I didn't want to install it as root. Your trick with `DESTDIR` solved it. Thank you!

Comment: @Jonas it won't run from the location where you install it with `DESTDIR`. If you want to install it runnably somewhere else than default, use `prefix` when building it (**before** `make install`).